# How do i use prettier with svelte?

Tags: svelte, prettier

Do I to delete the VsCode extension and press yes when svelte asks me to use it? Or do i keep the extension and just say no when svelte asks me?

I have tried both of these options but i keep on getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean for .svelte files?
In that case, you should have the svelte-vscode extension installed and edit your settings.json as described in the **Setup** instructions on the corresponding [extension details](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svelte.svelte-vscode).